# How to set password attribute to EditTextPreference dynamically like android:password="true"?

Tags: java, android

How can I set this EditTextPreference like android:password="true"?

```
    EditTextPreference editTextPreference = new EditTextPreference(screen.getContext());
    editTextPreference.setKey("password");
    editTextPreference.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.strTitle));
    editTextPreference.setSummary(getResources().getString(R.string.strSum));
    category.addPreference(editTextPreference);
```

Comment: have you tried edittext.setInputType() ? you can get the edit text from the edittextpreference with getEditText();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EditText editText = (EditText) editTextPreference.getEditText();
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: How can  add editText  to category.addPreference(editTextPreference);?

Comment: @RuntimeError Just call `category.addPreference(editTextPreference);`, it'll get added automatically.

Comment: It seems work. InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD

Comment: I missed that. Edited my answer now.